# Set ListBox item data format c#

Tags: c#, listbox

Sorry if the title make you feel confusing because of my bad english.
I have a ListBox which contain many items which have time format
(For example: 00:02:22:33)
I want to convert this time format into minutes

```
For example: 00:02:22:33 -> 02 hours = 120 minutes
                             33 seconds = 33/60 = 0.55 minutes
So result is 120+22+0.55 = 142.55
```

What i'm trying is writing a method like:

```
public static void Timeconvert(ListBox l) 
   {   
     foreach (var item in l.Items)
     {
        int x, int y, int z;             //It just to show you my thought
        if(item.format = 00:x:y:z)       
          {                                  
           int result =  x*60 +y + z/60 ;
           item = result.Tostring();
          }
     } 
  }
```

I'm new to C# so i explained as detail as i could, so please help me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just parse the string as span of time and use `TotalMinutes` property.

```
var time = TimeSpan.Parse("00:02:22:33");
var convertedToMinutes = time.TotalMinutes;  //Returns 142.55
```

This will update your list items

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.Parse(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
    listBox1.Items[i] = time.TotalMinutes;
}
```

Alternately, `TryParse()` can be used for handling strings in an incorrect format: `if (TimeSpan.TryParse(listBox1.Items[i].ToString(), out time)) { listBox1.Items[i] = time.TotalMinutes; }`

Comment: Thanks you so much !

Answer (score 0):

You may try following:

```
var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"00:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}");
foreach (var item in l.Items)
{
    if (regex.IsMatch(item))
    {
        item =  TimeSpan.Parse(item).TotalMinutes.ToString();
    }
}
```